# How do I take certain values from a dataframe, average them, and place them in a new dataframe in r?

Tags: r

I have a data frame that contains two columns. Column V1 contained coordinates for a 96 well plate ie, A1, A2, A3, and so on until H12. Column V2 contains integer values for each cell. Say cell A6 and A12 are values for a certain treatment in the plate. How would I average these values and place them in a new data frame with the first column being the name of the treatment, the second being the average, and the third being the standard deviation?

In the end, I would like a bar graph with error bars. I have many plates so it became too cumbersome to make in excel.
This is how they look in excel
[image]

Here is a small example dataframe

```r
data <- data.frame(Cell = c("A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5", "A6", "A7", "A8", "A9", "A10", "A11", "A12"),
                   Value = c(4, 6, 2, 7, 4, 6, 1, 6, 2, 3, 4, 6))
```

Say cells A6 and A12 represent treatment A. I would like a new data frame like this:

```r
result <- data.frame(Treatment = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"),
                   Mean = c(6, 6, 2, 7, 4, 6),
                   SD = c(0, 2, 1.5, .75, 5, 2))
```

Comment: Please provide a sample data, and what you tried. I suggest you check out  https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_linerange.html for error bars

Comment: Just use `data |> group_by(Treatment) |> summarize(Mean = mean(Value), SD=sd(Value))`.

Answer (score 0):

Using tidyverse library to subset cells containing "6" and "12", and take the first letter to create a new grouping variable for treatment:

```
library(tidyverse)

data <- data %>% 
  filter(grepl("6", Cell) | grepl("12", Cell)) %>% 
  mutate(treatment = substr(Cell, 1, 1)) 

  Cell Value treatment
1   A6     6         A
2  A12     6         A
```

Summarise by group:

```
data %>% 
  group_by(treatment) %>%
  summarise(mean = mean(Value), sd = sd(Value))

# A tibble: 1 x 3
    treatment  mean    sd
    <chr>     <dbl> <dbl>
  1 A             6     0
```

Comment: How would I do this over and over again for all the cells A1-H12? [link](http://example.com) _italic_ **bold** `MB468DOX_4 <- MB468DOX %>% 
  filter(grepl("H2", V1) | grepl("B4", V1)) %>% 
  mutate(treatment = "BBQ 1")` This is my code now. The treatments are mostly groups of two cells.

Comment: The code works for the 6th and 12th cell for all treatment.  Since the data you provided is only for treatment A, I assumed that you wanted A6, A12, B6, B12, ... If you need other conditions, please edit your question and clarify.

Comment: The code I added in the comment groups cells H2 and B4 as treatment BBQ 1. My treatments are spread randomly throughout the plate so I need to be able to specify specific cells not just all cells with 6 or 12. That was just an example. I would want to append BBQ 2 which is H3 and C4 and so on. I have 40 different treatments so I have a lot of combinations.

Comment: Write down the cells you want in a vector, e.g. `wanted <- c("A6", "A12", "H2", "B4")`. Then instead of `grepl` use `filter(Cell %in% wanted)`. I don't know what you mean by BBQ. Please provide a better reproducible dataset and what you want the outcome to be.

Comment: BBQ is just the name of the treatment. I might as well be called "treatment 1"